# Alternate Access Mapping - Intranet

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping

I need to give a Intranet URL for the company folks to access the Central Admin
. I have created a public URL under Alternate Access Mapping.

My central admin url is somethinlike `http://shaamil_vm:5555/`

The Intranet Url specified in AAM is `http://ca.myapps.comany.lk`

When we browse the site using the AAM url `http://ca.myapps.comany.lk` I do not get directed to the central admin instead get the IIS manager window below.

Can anybody shed some light ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Add `http://ca.myapps.comany.lk` as an intranet url in AAM
2. Open the IIS manager. Select central admin site and edit the bindings

Also make sure `http://ca.myapps.comany.lk` is properly configured in DNS

**Update**

1. Go into IIS Manager
2. Right-click your site and choose Edit Bindings
3. Add a new http site binding with the cname in the Host Name box

Comment: Thank for the reply. steps 1 & 3 are done. Can I know how to set the bindings in IIS manager ? the binding asks for IP's and ports...

Comment: see my edit....